# Execute SSIS Package Script Task From Stored Procedure Get Variable Value

Tags: sql, ssis, package, integration

I have an SSIS package that takes in (through a package parameter) a value, passes it into a script task via a script variable (readonly variable), converts it to another value inside the script task, and finally writes that value out to another script variable (readwrite variable).  There are no other SSIS modules in the package aside from the one script task.

What I would like to do, from outside the package (via SQL) is:

1. Call the SSIS package, passing in a value for my parameter and variable
2. Get the value of the read/write variable that is determined at the end of the script task execution

I've got step **#1** working, just can't figure out **#2**.

How do I get the value of package variable in an SSIS package after it has executed?  Is it accessible?  Is it stored anywhere or can I store it somewhere in the SSIS catalog?   I've tried to see if it's stored in the SSISDB.[catalog].executions table somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be.

Do I need to write that script variable to a package parameter in order to see it from SQL after execution? Could I then perhaps see it by using EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].get_parameter_values, or does that only show parameter values before package execution?  Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SSIS only passes out logs. If this is SSIS 2012 you can probably use the management views in the SSIS catalog to pick up variables values but it isn't recommended. What you're doing is _very_ convoluted. There might be an easier way if you want to explain what you're actually trying to do. So please post the version of SSIS and SQL (2008, 2012, 2104), and what you're actually trying to do. What does the script task do and are you trying to call the package from SQL and get a result in SQL?

Comment: Sure thing.  It's SQL Sever 2012.

I basically have a bunch small pieces of code that someone wrote in VB years ago -- mostly very simple, with one input, one output that prepares data for the mainframe. The 'work' in the middle is pretty convoluted though.  The organization I work for wants to integrate this VB code with some SQL stored procedures, but they don't want me to spend time rewriting the logic in SQL.  So my approach is to call an package with the VB code in a script task from SQL and grab the output variable from the package execution and continue rolling in the stored proc.

Comment: Sounds like what I'm actually trying to do lives by a different name -- a CLR function.

Comment: Yes you could try wrapping it up in a CLR function which has it's own quirks but it's definitely less 'disconnected' than trying to go through SSIS and script tasks etc. How does the EXE you are calling accept and return parameters? If it's all on the command line, and even easier way is to use xp_cmdshell, though you need to loosen up security a little.

Comment: We really need to see your script code or understand how you are communicating with the VB modules. Are they compiled to command line EXE's or are they COM DLL's? Using SSIS to write results to a table is OK until you run it in parallel - then whatever execution ran last overwrites its result. Also please specify the version, mainly SQL 2008 (BIDS) or SQL 2012 (SSDT)\

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add one last step to the package to write the value of the variable to a table.

Then you can retrieve the value from the table via SQL.

You can either truncate the table every time, or keep a permanent history associated with each time the package runs.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I did go ahead and implement this -- what I'm not sure how to do now is tie a specific execution to the value in the table.  Is there a system variable I can also throw in my table with this variable that would allow me to tie it to a specific instance/execution of the package?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I would have to create a custom variable that will be unique for every execution.   I'd probably use some kind of datetime stamp, if it were me.

Comment: Both SSIS 2008 and ssis 2012 have an inbuilt execution id.... but how will you tie that back to a specific call to the package? In SSIS 2012 you can capture the execution id at call time (when using catalog stored procedures) but I suggest you investigate the xp_cmdshell or CLR route instead.